# Find string contanining spaces in MATLAB using regular expression

Tags: regex, matlab

Supose that we have this code:

```
a = 'aa bb+cc';
start_part = regexp(a, '^(\w+)\+','tokens');
```

I want 'aa bb' together as output with and without using structures like `[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]`. Anyway to do this?

**Ps.**
We don't know exact number of spaces in the fist sentence before + sign. This is just an example. for example we can have 'aa bb cc+dd' or 'aa bb dd hh+mm'.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Does [`^(\w+\s+\w+)\+`](https://regex101.com/r/fH0vD9/2) work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev I added some information to question.

Comment: Try [`^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)\+`](https://regex101.com/r/fH0vD9/3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a sequence of several words at the beginning of a string that are space-separated, you can use

```
^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fH0vD9/5), [sample code](http://goo.gl/clF1q3):

```
ax = 'aa bb ee gg+cc+dd';
start_part = regexp(ax, '^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)\+','tokens');
disp(start_part)
```

Result:  `[1,1] = aa bb ee gg`

This will match

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - (Capture group 1) matching...

  - `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
  - `(?:\s+\w+)*` - 0 or more sequences of 1 or more whitespaces followed with 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
- `\+` - a literal plus symbol

The `*` quantifier allows matching `aa` in `aa+bb`, and `aa bb` in `aa bb+cc`. If you need to only match 2+ word sequences, use `+`:

```
^(\w+(?:\s+\w+)+)\+
```

Comment: :) The last regex looks soooo positive :)